# Существуют ли web-хостинги с поддержкой загрузки изображений на сервер?

Tags: php, apache, веб-программирование

Существуют ли web-хостинги с поддержкой загрузки изображений на сервер?

Comment: что значит `с поддержкой загрузки изображений на сервер`? Севетую уточнить и подробнее написать, что вы имеете в виду. Ибо в текущем формате вопроса можно сказать, что любой хостинг позволяет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Необходима загрузка изображений на web-хостинг. Скажите пожалуйста, что именно нужно уточнить, потмоу что я не знаю что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: @gilo1212 Алексей пытался сказать, что ваш вопрос звучит примерно так: "Существует ли хлеб в хлебном магазине?"

Comment: Ну может вы имеете в виду загрузку через панель управления аккаунта, а может загрузку с помощью серверного скрипта, а-ля `php` или может быть вообще какой-то облачный сервис....а может за счет `curl`.... 1 и 2 пункт любой хост позволяет. Даже бесплатный....вот `curl` дело другое

Comment: @Blacknife Большое спасибо за ответ, и за приятный бонус, в качетсве шутки. )

Comment: @gilo1212 да не за что, ведь без шуток всё становится дьявольски скучным

Comment: вы отредактировали вопрос, **кардинально** его изменив. лучше было задать новый вопрос (кнопка в правом верхнем углу страницы).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin прикол в том, что отредактировал даже не автор, а другой человек

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, и даже приняли правку не автор, а проверяльщики

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, так, может быть, её стоит откатить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так любой платный хостинг разрешает загружать изображения..
будь то shared (виртуальный) хостинг, vps или облачный..

Answer (score 1):

Да, облачные хостинги называются. Так же подойдет VDS/VPS. Я думаю у вас другая проблема. У apache не хватает прав на заливку файлов. Вы можете загрузить их через FTP.

Чтобы ваш сайт мог заргужать картинки, ваш системный администратор должен сделать следующее.

> Нужно заходить на сервер по ssh и с помощью chown менять группу на
>   www-data Еще права на директории нужно будет выставить в 0775

Comment: Dmitry Да, у нас  apache. Просто мы хотим что бы была возможно загружать аваторки для пользователей, и изображение хранились у нас.

Comment: Данный вопрос крайне плохо сформулирован. Если вы каким–либо образом догадались, что именно подразумевал автор, пожалуйста, опубликуйте отдельный вопрос сразу с ответом. Практика показывает, что столь значимые изменения вопроса от автора одного из ответов могут привести к спорам с другими участниками.